# Pass the Bluetooth connection between Activities in Android Studio

Tags: android, bluetooth, connection

I found a very simple example for Bluetooth connection with Arduino here.
http://www.instructables.com/id/Android-Bluetooth-Control-LED-Part-2/
Download full project: 
http://www.instructables.com/id/Android-Bluetooth-Control-LED-Part-2/step9/Download/
Many thanks for the Author Deyson !
It hase two Acitvities:
    1) DeviceList.java
    This showing the paired devices and You can select the desired one:

```
package com.led.led;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Set;


public class DeviceList extends ActionBarActivity
{
//widgets
Button btnPaired;
ListView devicelist;
//Bluetooth
private BluetoothAdapter myBluetooth = null;
private Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices;
public static String EXTRA_ADDRESS = "device_address";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_device_list);

    //Calling widgets
    btnPaired = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    devicelist = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

    //if the device has bluetooth
    myBluetooth = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    if(myBluetooth == null)
    {
        //Show a mensag. that the device has no bluetooth adapter
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth Device Not Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        //finish apk
        finish();
    }
    else if(!myBluetooth.isEnabled())
    {
            //Ask to the user turn the bluetooth on
            Intent turnBTon = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(turnBTon,1);
    }

    btnPaired.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            pairedDevicesList();
        }
    });

}

private void pairedDevicesList()
{
    pairedDevices = myBluetooth.getBondedDevices();
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

    if (pairedDevices.size()>0)
    {
        for(BluetoothDevice bt : pairedDevices)
        {
            list.add(bt.getName() + "\n" + bt.getAddress()); //Get the device's name and the address
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Paired Bluetooth Devices Found.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    devicelist.setAdapter(adapter);
    devicelist.setOnItemClickListener(myListClickListener); //Method called when the device from the list is clicked

}

private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener myListClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
{
    public void onItemClick (AdapterView<?> av, View v, int arg2, long arg3)
    {
        // Get the device MAC address, the last 17 chars in the View
        String info = ((TextView) v).getText().toString();
        String address = info.substring(info.length() - 17);

        // Make an intent to start next activity.
        Intent i = new Intent(DeviceList.this, ledControl.class);

        //Change the activity.
        i.putExtra(EXTRA_ADDRESS, address); //this will be received at ledControl (class) Activity
        startActivity(i);
    }
};


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_device_list, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
   }
}
```

2) ledControl.java This is having the buttons and commuincation:

```
package com.led.led;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.UUID;


public class ledControl extends ActionBarActivity {

Button btnOn, btnOff, btnDis;
SeekBar brightness;
TextView lumn;
String address = null;
private ProgressDialog progress;
BluetoothAdapter myBluetooth = null;
BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;
private boolean isBtConnected = false;
//SPP UUID. Look for it
static final UUID myUUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent newint = getIntent();
    address = newint.getStringExtra(DeviceList.EXTRA_ADDRESS); //receive the address of the bluetooth device

    //view of the ledControl
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_led_control);

    //call the widgtes
    btnOn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btnOff = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    btnDis = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
    brightness = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    lumn = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lumn);

    new ConnectBT().execute(); //Call the class to connect

    //commands to be sent to bluetooth
    btnOn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            turnOnLed();      //method to turn on
        }
    });

    btnOff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            turnOffLed();   //method to turn off
        }
    });

    btnDis.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Disconnect(); //close connection
        }
    });

    brightness.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            if (fromUser==true)
            {
                lumn.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
                try
                {
                    btSocket.getOutputStream().write(String.valueOf(progress).getBytes());
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {

                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });
}

private void Disconnect()
{
    if (btSocket!=null) //If the btSocket is busy
    {
        try
        {
            btSocket.close(); //close connection
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        { msg("Error");}
    }
    finish(); //return to the first layout

}

private void turnOffLed()
{
    if (btSocket!=null)
    {
        try
        {
            btSocket.getOutputStream().write("TF".toString().getBytes());
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            msg("Error");
        }
    }
}

private void turnOnLed()
{
    if (btSocket!=null)
    {
        try
        {
            btSocket.getOutputStream().write("TO".toString().getBytes());
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            msg("Error");
        }
    }
}

// fast way to call Toast
private void msg(String s)
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_led_control, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private class ConnectBT extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>  // UI thread
{
    private boolean ConnectSuccess = true; //if it's here, it's almost connected

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        progress = ProgressDialog.show(ledControl.this, "Connecting...", "Please wait!!!");  //show a progress dialog
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... devices) //while the progress dialog is shown, the connection is done in background
    {
        try
        {
            if (btSocket == null || !isBtConnected)
            {
             myBluetooth = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();//get the mobile bluetooth device
             BluetoothDevice dispositivo = myBluetooth.getRemoteDevice(address);//connects to the device's address and checks if it's available
             btSocket = dispositivo.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(myUUID);//create a RFCOMM (SPP) connection
             BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().cancelDiscovery();
             btSocket.connect();//start connection
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            ConnectSuccess = false;//if the try failed, you can check the exception here
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) //after the doInBackground, it checks if everything went fine
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if (!ConnectSuccess)
        {
            msg("Connection Failed. Is it a SPP Bluetooth? Try again.");
            finish();
        }
        else
        {
            msg("Connected.");
            isBtConnected = true;
        }
        progress.dismiss();
    }
  }
}
```

So I put one more button in he ledControl.java to open the Third Page, called Programing:

```
btnProgram.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()  //Open programing page
{
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v)
   {                
     Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Programing.class);
     startActivity(i);
   }
});
```

The problem is the Third page not "remembering" on the bluetooth connection, so I can not send any information. I know some posts are here in the same topic as well. I tried many options, but without success.
If somebody can propose a simple code to keep alive the BT connection between Activities, it will be very benefitial for the beginners like me, 
So how is possible to PASS THE BT CONNECTION ON A SIMPEL WAY ?
I kinldy asking You, please put You proposal in the above codes.
Thank You for Your HELP in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a custom Application subclass, and store the bluetooth connection there. Then an activity could just ask for it from there, since it's around for the lifecycle of your application.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application
{

    private static MyApplication sInstance;

    public static MyApplication getApplication() {
        return sInstance;
    }

    BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        sInstance = this;
    }

    public void setupBluetoothConnection()
    {
        // Either setup your connection here, or pass it in
    }

    public BluetoothSocket getCurrentBluetoothConnection()
    {
        return btSocket;
    }
}
```

And in your activity call:

```
MyApplication.getInstance().setupBluetoothConnection();
```

And later:

```
MyApplication.getInstance().getCurrentBluetoothConnection();
```

You need to specify that your app uses this Application class in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name="com.yourpackage.MyApplication">
```

Another option would be to implement a custom Service that sets up / stores the bluetooth connection, but that is going to be more overhead and maintenance.

Comment: Thank You for Your prompt reply. I started to work on Your solution. So far the 'MyAppliCation.java' file exist any without error (I added 'import android.app.Application;'). The BT connection already estabilised in 'private class ConnectBT extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>  // UI thread'  & confirmed in 'protected void onPostExecute(Void result)' procedure. The next step shall be as You wrote to pass this conection in Your code, in procedure 'public void setupBluetoothConnection()' Please inform me how can I do ? Where I have to write the code in my program? Thank You for HELP.

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought, why don't keep all Bluetooth stuff & communication in a separate Service class which is not bound to Activity lifecycle?

You can communicate with Service via binder/intents or EventBus and decouple it from UI.

As a bonus from this solution, you will implement all the communication (send and recieve) only once and on just single place rather than having it in multiple activities.

Comment: @Rory hool i am confused in it please help me

Comment: i have made the service for bluetooth but connection is destroy when back button is pressed